# Filter out the fields in API response in React using fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have API response coming like below, I need to filter it out so that I should only get few fields out of this. e.g. I just need description and `placeLocation`.

> results: [{placeId: "BHLLC", placeLocation: "BUFR", locationType:  "BUFR",…},…]
> 0: {placeId: "BHLLC", placeLocation: "BUFR", locationType: "BUFR",…}
> binControl: "Y"
> description: "BUFR - Good Stock"
> locationType: "BUFR"
> ours: "Y"
> placeId: "BHLLC"
> placeLocation: "BUFR"
> transferIsUse: "Y"
> usable: "F"

I need to pass the fields in body inside the fetch.js file like below

```
const body = {
        criteria,
        fields: ["description", "placeLocation", "whosPlace"],
        skip: 0,
        take: 2000
    };
```

And then I am trying to map the results like this. Please note that places is the result of the fetches call to API calling function.

```
let result = [];
    if (places) {
        result = places.results.map(p => ({
            placeId: p.description, name: p.placeLocation
        }));
    }
```

the fetch function from fetch file look like below

```
export const fetchPlacesTo = async () => {

const criteria = [
    {
        anyOf: [
            {
                field: "WhosPlace",
                value: "L%",
                operator: "li"
            }
        ]
    }
];
const body = {
    criteria,
    fields: ["description", "placeLocation", "whosPlace"],
    skip: 0,
    take: 2000
};

const result = sessionManager
    .refreshFetch(
        `${**********_API_URI}/place/place`,
        fetchUtils.hwsGetRequest(body)
    )
    .then(parseResponse);

return result;

};
```

And the function which calls this is below

```
export const getPlacesTo = () => async dispatch => {
try {
    dispatch(loading.incrementLoading());

    const places = await fetches.fetchPlacesTo().catch(error => {
        console.log(error); //CRS: Change to logger
        dispatch(loading.setWarning(errors.ERROR_GET_DATA));
    });

    let result = [];
    if (places) {
        result = places.results.map(p => ({
            placeId: p.description, name: p.placeLocation
        }));
    }

    dispatch({
        type: constants.GET_LOOKUP_ENTITY,
        payload: {
            name: "placeIdToRepair",
            value: result
        }
    });
```

Comment: and what's the problem ?

Comment: It's not working, I am not even getting the responses.

Comment: please provide all the call function only this piece of code doesn't make too much sense

Comment: please share full JSON and what do you want explixitly

Comment: @EvandroCavalcateSantos have edited the post, added few more details. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want placeId and placeLocation froom response into result

```
var result=[]
var data={results: [{placeId: "BHLLC", placeLocation: "BUFR", locationType: "BUFR"},{placeId: "BHALC", placeLocation: "BAFR", locationType: "BAFR"},{placeId: "BHBLLC", placeLocation: "BUBFR", locationType: "BUBFR"}]}
data.results.map(p=>result.push({
            placeId: p.placeId, name: p.placeLocation
        }));
console.log(result)//(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
placeId: "BHLLC"
name: "BUFR"
__proto__: Object
1:
placeId: "BHALC"
name: "BAFR"
__proto__: Object
2:
placeId: "BHBLLC"
name: "BUBFR"
__proto__: Object
length: 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the moment I apply map on the API result the code is breaking and I am not getting any results.